# Is it possible to deploy an app to DigitalOcean without Git?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I want to deploy a Node.js app to DigitalOcean. Their dashboard doesn't provide an upload option. I googled how to deploy an app on their site but all I got was command line tutorials using Git.

I don't wanna use Git. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use FTP to upload your app source, and also you can access the server via SSH.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do that is: upload your application **.zip** to a drive solution like google drive or another one, with public access URL. Then, inside your droplet, you can download the file by using **wget** or **curl**, extract it and you're done.

Download

```
wget http://www.exampe.org/repos/app.zip
```

Extract (use unzip), if it is not installed yet, install using this command

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

After unzip is installed just extract the app like this

```
unzip app.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

have you looked into setting up an ftp server, you haven't mentioned the os you are using so i cant directly link you to a tutorial, but a google search should turn up instructions.

If you don't want to go that route you can do what a lot of new developers do and simply copy paste your code into the ssh terminal.

Comment: Assume that he has created the environment through the one-click app creation. Even that so, digitalocean provides SSH access.